# How do I get rid of unnecessary information in the Octave command line?

Tags: path, octave

I recently started using Octave, I don't really understand it yet, and the first inconveniences have already appeared.
[image]
Every time I want to use the command line to write even ordinary variables, the file path and the like are triggered before the response.

When using .bat was the same, but it was fixed with one line of code when writing the script. Maybe there is something similar here? Please tell me :)

It is not necessary to recommend clc and clear, this is a one-time promotion, then if you enter it, the path to the files appears again, etc.

Comment: This is not unnecessary information, it’s error messages. You want to fix the error!

Comment: This is probably because the program is installed in a path that contains non-ASCII  characters "Алексей". Try to reinstall Octave in a path that contains only ASCII characters like "C:\Programs\Octave" .

Comment: type `help warning` on your terminal to find out how to turn warnings on or off. however, as others have said, this warning is actually warning you of something important, that your 'path' is not working. have a look at `help path` in octave, and the related commands it mentions there to get you started checking and correcting this. For information how to issue commands that occur every time you start octave, see `.octaverc` here: https://docs.octave.org/interpreter/Startup-Files.html